# Calculate Gross amount when only percent is known

Tags: arithmetic

Consider Rs.1000 as my **Gross** salary and suppose 20% is **PF**.

so the simple thing is my **NET** amount is Rs.800.

But when I know only my **NET** amount i.e. Rs.800  and I know that my 20% PF is already removed. So How can I know my **Gross** Amount??

please help me. I am really stucked here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is p% of the gross $\mathbf{G}$, then
$$X = \frac{p}{100}\mathbf{G}.$$
Solving for $\mathbf{G}$, we have
$$\mathbf{G} = \frac{100X}{p}.$$

For example if your net is $1000$, and this is 80% of your gross, then
$$\text{Gross} = \frac{100(1000)}{80} = 1250.$$

Answer (score 1):

You have Net=80% Gross=0.8 * Gross so Gross=Net/0.8

Answer (score 1):

$= 800 \times \frac{20}{(100-20)}$

$= 800 \times \frac{20}{ 80}$

$= 800 \times 0.25$

$= 200$

Gross = $800+200$
Net = $1000$ Ans.